# TextformField Fillable

Tags: flutter

I add an icon in Textformfield, is there a way that the suffix icon can still be clicked when Textformfield is disabled?

if i enable that textfield, the text will fillable.

here's the code

```dart
TextFormField (
                     enabled: false,
                     decoration: InputDecoration (
                       filled: true,
                         prefixIcon: Icon (Icons.content_copy),
                         suffixIcon: IconButton (icon: Icon (
                           Icons.camera_alt,
                           color: Colors.orange,
                         ), onPressed: () {
                           print ("halooooooo");
                         }),
                         labelText: "Photo KTP *"),
                   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution here :

just add `readOnly : true`

```dart
TextFormField(
                    readOnly: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.content_copy),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(icon: Icon(
                          Icons.camera_alt,
                          color: Colors.orange,
                        ), onPressed: (){
                          print("halooooooo");
                        }),
                        labelText: "Foto KTP *"),
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't because if you check the source code of `TextFormField` and `TextField`, it's using a `IgnorePointer` widget based on the `enabled` property.

You can achieve the same using the `Row`  widget, check this code:

```
Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    enabled: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.content_copy),
                        labelText: "Photo KTP *"),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.camera_alt,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("halooooooo");
                    }),
              ],
            )
```

Comment: yes,, i want to doing like this... but i found solution.. thanks for answering.

Comment: Yes I saw you are using readOnly, but `enabled` property has more than that:  `If false the text field is "disabled": it ignores taps and its decoration is rendered in grey`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `TextFormField` with this

```
  Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      TextFormField(
        enabled: false,
        focusNode: FocusNode(),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.content_copy),
            labelText: "Photo KTP *"),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 10,
        bottom: 10,
        right: 10,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.camera_alt,
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
          onPressed: (){
            print('halloooo');
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

You can achieve same effect with something like this.

What is happening here?

I am using a `Stack` widget. With `Stack` we can put more than one element in the same space. With positioned I then put the camera button to the right side. The camera button will respond to touches.

### Edit:

[with read-only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBzO9.png)

You can get the button working with `read-only: true` but the input will trigger the textedit animation still.

With stack the input is truly disabled.

[with stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEc0n.png)

Comment: @Cong Fandi Although read-only will make the text non editable, the text edit animation will still trigger.